# using Case in select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a situation where I am summing up several columns from a table and inserting the results into another table. This is being grouped by county and district. One of the columns is also taking the smallest total sales from a retailer in that district. The problem I have is that there may be some that have less than zero total sales. I only want to write the smallest value that is greater than zero to that column.

```
declare @WeekEnd datetime
set @WeekEnd = (select top(1) date from sales order by date desc)
select date
,county
,district
,sum(prod1) 
,sum(prod2) 
,sum(prod3) 
,sum(prod4) 
,sum(prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4) --Total Sales
,Case when min(prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4) > 0 then min(prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4)
--this works well except for when a total is less than zero, then it is null. I want to avoid the null and have it write the smallest value greater than zero. 
end
from sales 
where date = @WeekEnd
group by date,county,district
order by county, district
```

Comment: add else condition too , else null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly, you need to get the MIN TotalSales with a subquery:

```
declare @WeekEnd datetime
set @WeekEnd = (select top(1) date from sales order by date desc)
select date
,county
,district
,sum(prod1) 
,sum(prod2) 
,sum(prod3) 
,sum(prod4) 
,sum(prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4) --Total Sales
,(SELECT min(prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4)
  FROM sales s2
  WHERE s1.date=s2.date
  AND s1.county=s2.county
  AND s1.district=s2.district
  AND (prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4)>0
)
from sales s1
where date = @WeekEnd
group by date,county,district
order by county, district
```

Comment: Perfect. I thought I tried a subquery but I must have left something out that was causing me to get errors. It doesn't matter now. Thanks your for help.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried, but I would assume this works:

```
min(Case when prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4 <= 0 
    then null else prod1+prod2+prod3+prod4 end)
```